# Is it the correct change?

Tags: analysis

Calculate the integral :

$\displaystyle\iint_D\sqrt{x-y}\;dxdy\;,$

where $\;D=\big\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\;\big|\; 1\leq y\leq4\;,\frac{4}{5}x\leq y\leq x\big\}\;.$

My attempt is :

$\displaystyle\int_1^4\int_y^{\frac{5y}{4}}\sqrt{x-y}\;dxdy$

but I did not know if it is correct change .

Comment: Yes it is correct but write the order of integral correctly. Internal integral is $dx$ and outer $dy$.

Comment: thanks sir, now im write the correct way

Comment: answer is $\frac{31}{15}\sqrt 2$ but in the book is $\frac{31}{30}$ which is correct

Comment: Book answer $\frac{31}{30}$ is correct. You may be making some mistake.

Comment: i find the mistake, thanks